# How to get back a signed string (e.g. md5 hash) using a public-key (x509 certificate)

Tags: python, m2crypto

I'm very new with cryptographic and stuck for 2 days with this problem, I hope you can help me with.

I try to sign a md5 digest string with the private key of a X509 certificate. As far as I can see, this works fine.
Now I try to get back that string using the public key of that x509 certificate, but I have no idea how to do this.

First I created a x509 certificate and a private-Keyfile using OpenSSL:

openssl req -newkey rsa:1024 -nodes -x509 -days 365 -out signer.pem

Here's the example code I tried:

```
import M2Crypto
import hashlib

def empty_callback ():
 return

# md5 hash of params
params = "0045KIABCDEFG"

m = hashlib.md5()
m.update(params)
md = m.digest()
print m.hexdigest()

M2Crypto.Rand.rand_seed (os.urandom (1024))

# sign md5 hash with private key
SignEVP = M2Crypto.EVP.load_key ('privkey.pem')
#Begin signing
SignEVP.sign_init ()
#Tell it to sign our string
SignEVP.sign_update (md)
#Get the final result
StringSignature = SignEVP.sign_final ()
#print the final result
print StringSignature.encode ('base64')
```

I get the public key with this, but don't know how to use it then.

objX509 = M2Crypto.X509.load_cert ('signer.pem')
PubKey = objX509.get_pubkey()

I only found how to verify the signed string, but that's not what I need.
Is there a method to get back the origin md5 digest (md) by using the signer.pem (the public key)?

I'm using M2Cyrpto-0.21.1 and OpenSSL 1.0.0d, and programming with Python27, 32bit on Windows7.

kind regards,
Falko

Comment: Technically, you are not supposed to "decrypt" the signature. What are you trying to do? If you want to verify the signature, it is done in some other way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically, you are not supposed to "decrypt" the signature. If you really want to decrypt it, do something like this:

```
cert = X509.load_cert("signer.pem")
decrypted = cert.get_pubkey().get_rsa().public_decrypt(StringSignature, 1)
```

but this will not give you what you are expecting, I guess.

If you want to pull out the message digest that was signed using the code above, you would have to decode the ASN.1 sequence in the `decrypted`. You can do this with PyCrypto, of course, but what for?

```
from Crypto.Util import asn1
seq = asn1.DerSequence()
seq.decode(decrypted)
obj = asn1.DerObject()
obj.decode(seq[1])
# now this is the original message digest that was signed
original_message_md = obj.payload
```

Comment: I try to write a Webserver-App dealing with signed URLs based on documentation. In this documentation they always speaking of 'signing' the URL, but meanwhile I think they mean encrypting the URL. So the first solution works fine for me. Thanks...